# Write A Program That Outputs Its Mirror Level

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, source-layout, printable-ascii

There are 95 [printable ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) characters:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

In the [Consolas font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas) (the Stack Exchange code block default), some of the characters have mirrors around a vertical axis of symmetry:

- These pairs of characters are mirrors of each other: `()` `[]` `{}` `<>` `/\`
- These characters are mirrors of themselves: `! "'*+-.8:=AHIMOTUVWXY^_ovwx|` (Note that space is one.)
- These do not have mirrors: `` #$%&,012345679;?@BCDEFGJKLNPQRSZ`abcdefghijklmnpqrstuyz~ ``

<sup>(`i`, `l`, `0`, `#`, and probably other characters are their own mirrors in some fonts but we'll stick to the Consolas shapes.)</sup>

A string is said to be a mirror of itself if it is made with **only the 39 mirror characters**, arranged such that the string has a central vertical line of symmetry. So `](A--A)[` is a mirror of itself but `](A--A(]` is not.

Write a one-line even-length program that is a mirror of itself. When N copies of its left half have been prepended to it and N copies of its right half have been appended to it, it should output N+1. N is a non-negative integer.

For example, if the program was `](A--A)[` (left half: `](A-`, right half: `-A)[`), then:

- Running `](A--A)[` should output `1`. (N = 0)
- Running `](A-](A--A)[-A)[` should output `2`. (N = 1)
- Running `](A-](A-](A--A)[-A)[-A)[` should output `3`. (N = 2)
- Running `](A-](A-](A-](A--A)[-A)[-A)[-A)[` should output `4`. (N = 3)
- . . .
- Running `](A-](A-](A-](A-](A-](A-](A-](A-](A-](A--A)[-A)[-A)[-A)[-A)[-A)[-A)[-A)[-A)[-A)[` should output `10`. (N = 9)
- etc.

#### Rules

- Output to stdout or your language's closest alternative. There may be an optional trailing newline. No input should be taken.
- The process should theoretically work for N up to 2<sup>15</sup>-1 or beyond, given enough memory and computing power.
- A full program is required, not just a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) command.

**The shortest initial program (N = 0 case) in bytes wins.**

Comment: In some fonts, `#` is its own relection as well, but, you're right, not in consolas.

Comment: Using repls is allowed? In other words: should we write a complete valid program or an expression is enough? I'm thinking about the Haskell entry which would work when running in ghci but isn't a valid complete program.

Comment: @Bakuriu A full program is required. The Haskell answer is invalid.

Comment: Why aren't 'b' and 'd' mirrors of eachother? It makes my plan impossible :P

Comment: @ThijsterHaar I actually didn't consider that but it looks like their Consolas shapes are just slightly different, sorry :P

Comment: Would `var rav;;var rav` qualify for this? It would output nothing. In Javascript, `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0` and `''` all are 'the same'. So, technically, this would be outputting it's mirror level. If that qualified, would `;;` qualify as well?

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies What do you mean?

Comment: But `0` is positive **AND** negative...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24283/discussion-between-calvins-hobbies-and-ismael-miguel).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Pip, <s>12</s> <s>8</s> 4 bytes

*Now with 66% fewer bytes!*

```
x++x
```

- `x` is a variable, preinitialized to `""`. In numeric context, this becomes `0`.
- The first half, sans the final `+`, makes an expression of the form `x+x+...+x`. This is a valid statement that does nothing.
- The second half, including the final `+` from the first half, makes an expression of the form `++x+x+...+x`. `++x` increments `x` to `1`, and the rest adds it to itself N times. Because expressions are evaluated left-to-right in Pip, the increment is guaranteed to happen first, and the result is equal to the number of mirror levels.
- At the end, the value of this expression is auto-printed.

Unfortunately, Pip doesn't do well processing huge expressions: this solution causes a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error for N above 500 or so. Here's a previous solution that doesn't, for **8 bytes**:

```
x++oo++x
```

[More on Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip)

Comment: OK, unless somebody posts a 2 byte answer, looks like you got this one in the bag. By the way, I don't know if you've run it with **N = 32767**, but the actual output is `Fatal error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, I ran into that actually--it starts quite early, around 600 if not before.  The reason is that expressions are evaluated by recursively evaluating all subexpressions first, so `x+x+...+x` generates O(N) depth of recursion.  Maybe that invalidates this answer.  I'll add a note.

Comment: The recursion limit is easily adjustable in Python, isn't it?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, although there are [dire warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?#sys.setrecursionlimit) about what it'll do to your system if you set it too high, so I've never tried it. ;) Besides, configuring it isn't possible from within *Pip*, so it seems kinda like cheating to me.  If you want to try it, though, I'd be interested in hearing the results.

Comment: I've tried. On my machine, increasing the recursion limit to 20000 already segfaults. But since the answer has to work only *given enough memory and computing power*, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ah, that's helpful.  I hadn't noticed `theoretically` in the problem description.

Comment: @DLosc About those dire warnings - Pyth's recursion limit is purposefully set high enough that it regularly segfaults. I've never noticed any other issue.

Comment: @isaacg Good to know.  ("Dire" was a bit of hyperbole on my part.  I just didn't know if it would cause system instability or not.)

Comment: Fun fact: trying to evaluate an expression that long even crashes *Python*.

Answer (score 34):

## GolfScript, 10 bytes

```
!:{)::(}:!
```

Try it online with Web Golfscript: [N = 0](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ITp7KTo6KH06IQ%3D%3D), [N = 1](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ITp7KTohOnspOjoofTohOih9OiE%3D), [N = 2](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6Oih9OiE6KH06IToofToh), [N = 3](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTo6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IQ%3D%3D), [N = 41](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6ITp7KTohOnspOiE6eyk6Oih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofTohOih9OiE6KH06IToofToh)

Web GolfScript has a 1024 character limit, but the Ruby interpreter handles **N = 32767** perfectly:

```
$ curl -Ss http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/golfscript.rb > golfscript.rb
$ echo '"!:{):"32768*":(}:!"32768*' | ruby golfscript.rb > mirror-level-32767.gs
$ ruby golfscript.rb mirror-level-32767.gs
32768
```

#### How it works

Without any input, GolfScript initially has an empty string on the stack.

In the first left half, the following happens:

- `!` applies logical NOT to the empty string. This pushes `1`.
- `:{` saves the integer on the stack in the variable `{`.

  Yes, that is a valid identifier, although there's no way to retrieve the stored value.
- `)` increments the integer on the stack.
- `:` is an incomplete instruction.

The the subsequent left halves, the following happens:

- `:!` (where `:` is a leftover from before) saves the integer on the stack in the variable `!`.

  Yes, that is also a valid identifier. This breaks the `!` command, but we don't use it anymore.
- `:{`, `)` and `:` work as before.

In the first right half, the following happens:

- `::` (where `:` is a leftover from before) saves the integer on the stack in the variable `:`.

  Yes, *even that* is valid identifier. As with `{`, there's no way to retrieve the stored value.
- `(` decrements the integer on the stack, yielding the number of left halves.
- `}`, since it is unmatched and terminates execution immediately.

  This is an undocumented feature. I call them *supercomments*.

The remaining code is simply ignored.

Comment: It seems really weird to have an unmatched `}` in the 2nd half of your code in a mirror competition.

Comment: It's a common trick in palindrome variants. In `"\""/"`, the fourth double quote would be unmatched as well since the second one has been escaped.

Answer (score 27):

## Z80 Machine Code, <s>8</s> 6 bytes*

`<8ww8>` * Assumes certain conditions by entering from Amstrad BASIC

```
<   INC A         // A=A+1
8w  JR C, #77     ## C is unset unless A has overflowed, does nothing

w   LD (HL), A    // Saves A to memory location in HL (randomly initialised)
8>  JR C, #3E     ## C is still unset, does nothing
```

`A` is initially 0 when entered from BASIC. It increments `A` *n* times, then writes it *n* times to the same memory location (which is set to a slightly random location by BASIC)! The `JR` Jump Relative operation never does anything since the `C` flag is always unset, so is used to "comment out" the following byte! This version is slightly cheating by assuming certain entry conditions, namely entering from BASIC guarantees that `A` is always 0. The location of `(HL)` is not guaranteed to be safe, and in fact, is probably a dangerous location. The below code is much more robust which is why it's so much longer.

## Z80 Machine Code, 30 bytes

As ASCII:
`o!.ww.!>A=o>{))((}<o=A<!.ww.!o`

Basically, the first half guarantees creation of a zero value and the second half increments it and writes it to memory. In the expanded version below `##` denotes code that serves no purpose in its half of the mirror.

```
o   LD L, A       ## 
!.w LD HL, #772E  // Load specific address to not corrupt random memory!
w   LD (HL), A    ## Save random contents of A to memory
.!  LD L, #21     ## 
>A  LD A, #41     // A=#41
=   DEC A         // A=#40
o   LD L, A       // L=#40
>{  LD A, #7B     ## 
)   ADD HL, HL    // HL=#EE80
)   ADD HL, HL    // HL=#DD00. L=#00 at this point

((  JR Z, #28     ## 
}   LD A, L       // A=L
<   INC A         // A=L+1
o   LD L, A       // L=L+1
=   DEC A         // A=L
A   LD B, C       ## 
<   INC A         // A=L+1
!.w LD HL, #772E  // Load address back into HL
w   LD (HL), A    // Save contents of A to memory
.!  LD L, #21     ## 
o   LD L, A       // L=A
```

Breakdown of allowed instructions:

```
n   op    description
--  ----  -----------
28  LD    LoaD 8-bit or 16-bit register
3   DEC   DECrement 8-bit or 16-bit register
1   INC   INCrement 8-bit or 16-bit register
1   ADD   ADD 8-bit or 16-bit register

Available but useless instructions:
3   JR    Jump Relative to signed 8-bit offset
1   DAA   Decimal Adjust Accumulator (treats the A register as two decimal digits
          instead of two hexadecimal digits and adjusts it if necessary)
1   CPL   1s ComPLement A
1   HALT  HALT the CPU until an interrupt is received
```

Out of the 39 instructions allowed, 28 are load operations (the block from 0x40 to 0x7F are all single byte `LD` instructions), most of which are of no help here! The only load to memory instruction still allowed is `LD (HL), A` which means I have to store the value in `A`. Since `A` is the only register left with an allowed `INC` instruction this is actually quite handy!

I can't load `A` with 0x00 to start with because ASCII 0x00 is not an allowed character! All the available values are far from 0 and all mathematical and logical instructions have been disallowed! Except... I can still do `ADD HL, HL`, add 16-bit `HL` to itself! Apart from directly loading values (no use here!), INCrementing `A` and DECrementing `A`, `L` or `HL` this is the only way I have of changing the value of a register! There is actually one specialised instruction that could be helpful in the first half but a pain to work around in the second half, and a ones-complement instruction that is almost useless here and would just take up space.

So, I found the closest value to 0 I could: 0x41. How is that close to 0? In binary it is 0x01000001. So I decrement it, load it into `L` and do `ADD HL, HL` twice! `L` is now zero, which I load back into `A`! Unfortunately, the ASCII code for `ADD HL, HL` is `)` so I now need to use `(` twice. Fortunately, `(` is `JR Z, e`, where `e` is the next byte. So it gobbles up the second byte and I just need to make sure it doesn't do anything by being careful with the `Z` flag! The last instruction to affect the `Z` flag was `DEC A` (counter-intuitively, `ADD HL, HL` doesn't change it) and since I know that `A` was 0x40 at that point it's guaranteed that `Z` is not set.

The first instruction in the second half `JR Z, #28` will do nothing the first 255 times because the Z flag can only be set if A has overflowed from 255 to 0. After that the output will be wrong, however since it's only saving 8-bits values anyway that shouldn't matter. The code shouldn't be expanded more than 255 times.

The code has to be executed as a snippet since all available ways of returning cleanly have been disallowed. All the RETurn instructions are above 0x80 and the few Jump operations allowed can only jump to a positive offset, because all 8-bit negative values have been disallowed too!

Comment: WHAT.  WHAT IS THIS.

Comment: Now I've seen this answer, using GolfScript/J/etc. just seems like cheating. :p

Comment: Are there Z80-compatible processors with a 16-bit A register? I'm asking since the question requires the code has to work for **N = 32767**.

Comment: @Dennis For a program to work for **N = 32767** it must be at least **2 x 32767** or **65534** bytes long. The Z80 can only address 65536 bytes of memory, making this an impossible task since I don't believe I can make the program smaller than 6 bytes! The `A` register is always 8 bits, otherwise the processor would not be compatible with the Z80. I would say that _given enough memory and computing power_ has been covered off here!

Comment: 16-bit version using forbidden instruction `#` (INC HL): `o#8"}88{"8#o` (12 bytes). Can fit into memory 5461 times but due to safe memory restrictions can actually only go 2800 times.

Comment: It was more of a curiosity. I'm not the one to judge this answer's validity and it's certainly ingenious, but you'll have to admit that using machine code that, by definition, cannot work for a processor that understands it is a little bold. Then again, this is code golf, where rules are meant to be bent.

Comment: @Dennis What do you mean by code that doesn't work for the processor? All the code I've posted runs just fine on a Z80. If you're referring to "a 16-bit A register" then that is the register pair HL. The only solutions I've found using HL (for a 16-bit version) either use instructions forbidden by this contest or output more than just the number required, which I believe would make it invalid. I believe my answer fully complies with the spirit of this question, even if not entirely the letter.

Comment: I meant that, while your code works for small values of `N` and could in theory work for larger ones, the compatible processors are incapable of handling the largest test case. I fully agree wirh your last sentence.

Comment: @Dennis You understand why no Z80 compatible processor will have an `A` register of anything other than 8 bits? Changing it to 16-bits would break code _relying_ on 255+1=0 for example. You would have to invent a CPU, lets call it the Z160, that uses a default 16-bit register but still uses the same 8-bit instruction set from the Z80. Weird!

Answer (score 20):

## J, <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
(_=_)]++[(_=_)
```

Usages:

```
   (_=_)]++[(_=_)
1
   (_=_)]+(_=_)]++[(_=_)+[(_=_)
2
   (_=_)]+(_=_)]+(_=_)]++[(_=_)+[(_=_)+[(_=_)
3
```

Explanation:

- J evaluates from right to left.
- `(_=_)` is `inf equals inf` which is true, has a value of `1`, so the expression becomes `1+]...[+1`. (`(8=8)` would also work but this looks cooler. :))
- `[` and `]` return their the left and right arguments respectively if they have 2 arguments. If they get only 1 they return that.
- `+` adds the 2 arguments. If it gets only 1 it returns that.

Now let's evaluate a level 3 expression (going from right to left):

```
(_=_)]+(_=_)]++[(_=_)+[(_=_)  NB. (_=_) is 1

1]+1]+1]++[1+[1+[1  NB. unary [, binary +

1]+1]+1]++[1+[2  NB. unary [, binary +

1]+1]+1]++[3  NB. unary [, unary +

1]+1]+1]+3  NB. unary +, binary ]

1]+1]+3  NB. unary +, binary ]

1]+3  NB. unary +, binary ]

3
```

As we see the right half of the `1`'s gets added and the left side of the `1`'s gets omitted resulting in the desired integer `N`, the mirror level.

[Try it online here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Answer (score 11):

## CJam, 14 bytes

```
]X+:+OooO+:+X[
```

Try it online in the CJam interpreter: [N = 0](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5DX%2B%3A%2BOooO%2B%3A%2BX%5B), [N = 1](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOooO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5B), [N = 2](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOooO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5B), [N = 3](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOooO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5B), [N = 41](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOo%5DX%2B%3A%2BOooO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5BoO%2B%3A%2BX%5B)

Note that this code finishes with an error message. Using the Java interpreter, that error message can be suppressed by closing or redirecting STDERR.<sup>1</sup>

#### How it works

In the left halves, the following happens:

- `]` wraps the entire stack in an array.
- `X` appends `1` to that array.
- `:+` computes the sum of all array elements.
- `Oo` prints the contents of empty array (i.e., nothing).

In the first right half, the following happens:

- `o` prints the integer on the stack, which is the desired output.
- `O+` attempts to append an empty array to the topmost item of the stack.

  However, the stack was empty before pushing `O`. This fails and terminates the execution of the program.

The remaining code is simply ignored.

<sup>1</sup><sub>According to the meta poll [Should submissions be allowed to exit with an error?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4780), this is allowed.</sub>

Comment: I'd be skeptical on accepting this due to the error thing, but since its not winning I'm not too concerned.

Comment: Tasks like this one are suprisingly hard in CJam, considering that it is a golfing language. Even a syntax error (e.g., an undefined operator) in a *unexecuted* block will prevent the entire program from executing. I'm still trying to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 11):

## Haskell, 42 bytes

```
(8-8)-(-(8-8)^(8-8))--((8-8)^(8-8)-)-(8-8)
```

Luckily a line comment in Haskell (-> `--`) is mirrorable and half of it (-> `-`) is a valid function. The rest is some math to get the numbers `0` and `1`. Basically we have `(0)-(-1)` with a comment for `N=0` and prepend `(0)-(-1)-` in each step.

If floating point numbers are allowed for output, we can build `1` from `8/8` and get by with 26 bytes:

## Haskell, 26 bytes

```
(8-8)-(-8/8)--(8\8-)-(8-8)
```

Outputs `1.0`, `2.0`, etc.

Comment: This is technically invalid since it must be a full program.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies: I see. Do we have consensus on the minimum requirements for a full program? I've searched meta, but only found a discussion about functions, not programs. Depending on the definition of a full program I might be able to fix my solution.

Comment: I'd call it a full program if you can save it in a file `program.hs` and then run `$ runhaskell program.hs` from the command line and see the output. I don't know Haskell so I can't say exactly what needs to change.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies: `runhaskell` is a shell script that sets up some environment and finally calls `ghc`, the Haskell compiler. You can run my code directly with `ghc`: `ghc -e "(8-8)-(-8/8)--(8\8-)-(8-8)"`. This launches `ghc` which evaluates the code provided as an argument, prints the result and exits. No REPL, no interaction. Of course this would add +1 to the byte count for `-e`.

Comment: @nimi: `-e` doesn't contribute to the score in this case. We don't count bytes for `perl -E` or `gcc -std=c99` either.